# Find locus of Q of an equalateral triangle APQ with A fixed and P moving along a line

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, locus, geometric-transformation

> ABC is an equilateral triangle with vertex A fixed and B moving in a given straight line. Find the locus of C

I drew some figures and realised that locus is a straight line and the part left is to prove

Now, consider a equilateral triangle ABC and consider a line $l$ passing through B. Let us take any point P on line $l$,join PQ and AQ. As per question this new triangle APQ must be equilateral.This is what I have to prove

After thinking for some time and doing some work, i realised that to prove the statement it suffice to prove that 
$ABP \cong ACQ$. I am struggling to prove it.I thought about in all ways but still i am unable to prove it (try to prove it by only pure elementary method )
EDIT: here angle APQ = 60.

[image]

Comment: How do you know if BCQ is collinear?

Comment: I edited .They can be collinear iff B coincides P

Comment: Suppose $Q$ does lie on the line $BC$. Then we have $\angle ABQ=\angle APQ$, so $ABPQ$ is cyclic. So $\angle AQP+\angle ABP=180^\circ$, so $\angle QBP=60^\circ$. In other words, the locus is only the line $BC$ in the special case that the angle between the line $\ell$ and the line $BC$ is $60^\circ$. Of course, you can always find a point $B'$ on the line $\ell$ st $AB'$ makes an angle $60^\circ$ with $\ell$. Then the required locus is the line making an angle $60\circ$ with both $\ell$ and $AB'$.

Comment: Let $\measuredangle BAP=\alpha$. Then, we have $\measuredangle PAC=60^0-\alpha$. Similarly, $\measuredangle CAQ=60^0-\left(60^0-\alpha\right)=\alpha$. Therefore, the two triangles $ABP$ and $ACQ$ have the condition called $\bf\rm{SAS}$ for them to be congruent.

Comment: Here you assumed that angle PAQ is 60 but it is not given

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In general, it can be shown that the locus of the vertex Q is

$$(\sqrt3 -\tan\theta)x-(\sqrt3\tan\theta +1)y = a(\sqrt3+\tan\theta)\tag 1$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the lines BQ and BP and the $a$ is the side length of the equilateral triangle ABC. Note that the locus (1) is a straight line. However, it does not coincide with the line BQ, as assumed in the question. Only in the special case of $\theta = 60^\circ$, it is so as the locus (1) reduces to

$$ y = -\frac{\sqrt3}2a$$

Assume then $\theta = 60$. It can be shown geometrically that the triangle APQ is equilateral. Extend AB to D and construct the equilateral triangle BDP. Given that $\angle APD = \angle BPQ$, $\angle ADP = \angle QBP$, as well as BP = DP, the triangles ADP and QBP are congruent. Thus, AP = QP = AQ.

Comment: At vertex B how did you knew that other two angles are 60??

Comment: @MathematicalCuriosity - If you want prove that the points B, C and Q are colinear, you have to assume $\angle QBP = 60$. Otherwise, the locus of the vertex Q is given by the general equation (1).

Answer (score 0):

Observe a rotation around $A$ for $60^{\circ}$.

This map takes $B$ to $C$, so when $B$ describes a line $\ell$ then $C$ describes a line $\ell'$ which a picture of $\ell$ under this rotation.